# Where is the float error in my python code

Tags: python

There is a float calling error somewhere and I just cant find it

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = 32.2  

rho = 0.00231  

S = 279  

W = 7000  

c0 = 928

c1 = 0.1

c2 = -0.002

d0 = 0.2

d1 = 0.0015

V0 = 0  

x0 = 0  

alpha0 = np.radians(-7)  

alpha_gr = np.radians(4)  

efficiency = 0.9  

lift_slope = np.radians(0.1167)  

max_lift_coef = 2.1  

dt = 0.05  



def thrust(V):

    return c0 + c1*V + c2*V**2



def drag_fuselage_tail(V):

    return d0*V + d1*V**2


def lift(V, alpha):

    return 0.5 * rho * V**2 * S * (lift_slope * alpha + max_lift_coef)


def drag(V, alpha):

    return 0.5 * rho * V**2 * S * (0.009 + (max_lift_coef(V, alpha)**2) / (np.pi * efficiency * S)) 


def acceleration(V, alpha):

    return (thrust(V) - drag(V, alpha) - drag_fuselage_tail(V)) / W - g * np.sin(alpha)


def rk4_step(V, x, alpha):

    k1v = dt * acceleration(V, alpha)

    k1x = dt * V

    k2v = dt * acceleration(V + (0.5)*k1v, alpha)

    k2x = dt * (V + (0.5)*k1v)

    k3v = dt * acceleration(V + (0.5)*k2v, alpha)

    k3x = dt * (V + (0.5)*k2v)

    k4v = dt * acceleration(V + k3v, alpha)

    k4x = dt * (V + k3v)

    

    V += (k1v + 2*k2v + 2*k3v + k4v) / 6

    x += (k1x + 2*k2x + 2*k3x + k4x) / 6

    

    return V, x


def takeoff():

    V = V0

    x = x0

    alpha = alpha0

    iterations = 0

    drag_values = []

    thrust_values = []

    while x >= 0:

        V, x = rk4_step(V, x, alpha)

        iterations += 1

        drag_values.append(drag(V, alpha))

        thrust_values.append(thrust(V))

        if alpha == alpha0:

            alpha = alpha_gr  

    return x, V, iterations, drag_values, thrust_values

SLO_distance, SLO_velocity, iterations, drag_values, thrust_values = takeoff()

time_to_liftoff = iterations * dt


print("Lift-off distance:", SLO_distance, "ft")

print("Lift-off velocity:", SLO_velocity, "ft/s")

print("Time to lift-off:", time_to_liftoff, "s")

print("RK4 iterations to lift-off:", iterations)


position = np.arange(0, SLO_distance, dt)

plt.plot(position, drag_values, label='Drag')

plt.plot(position, thrust_values, label='Thrust')

plt.xlabel('Position (ft)')

plt.ylabel('Force (lbs)')

plt.legend()

plt.title('Drag and Thrust vs. Position')

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

I have tried putting in quotations around things and its not working

```
C:\Users\goodm>python "C:\Users\goodm\Downloads\hw2 hopefully.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\goodm\Downloads\hw2 hopefully.py", line 126, in <module>
    SLO_distance, SLO_velocity, iterations, drag_values, thrust_values = takeoff()
                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\goodm\Downloads\hw2 hopefully.py", line 112, in takeoff
    V, x = rk4_step(V, x, alpha)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\goodm\Downloads\hw2 hopefully.py", line 69, in rk4_step
    k1v = dt * acceleration(V, alpha)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\goodm\Downloads\hw2 hopefully.py", line 64, in acceleration
    return (thrust(V) - drag(V, alpha) - drag_fuselage_tail(V)) / W - g * np.sin(alpha)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\goodm\Downloads\hw2 hopefully.py", line 59, in drag
    return 0.5 * rho * V**2 * S * (0.009 + (max_lift_coef * ((V, alpha))**2) / (np.pi * efficiency * S))
                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Comment: please post full error message

Comment: Its generally bad form to correct the original problem and then add a traceback for a new problem.   It invalidates the answer given for the original issue you had.  changing the code that was there also makes it more confusing for folks to give help.

Comment: your current stack is telling you exactly what the issue is the (v, alpha) tuple can not be exponentiated.  what are you trying to do with v and alpha on that line?

Answer (score 0):

based on your error message the block of code here:

```
def drag(V, alpha):

    return 0.5 * rho * V**2 * S * (0.009 + (max_lift_coef(V, alpha)**2) / (np.pi * efficiency * S))
```

Has the max_lift_coef being used as a function.   It is a float when used in that line.